# In MapReduce, how does reduce task differ from reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In Mapreduce, How does Reduce task differ from Reducer?

What is the correlation between reduce task and reducer?

Does Reducer perform the reduce task?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reduce task` is simply an instance of the `Reducer.`

The number of reduce tasks is configurable.

Either it can be specified by setting property `mapred.reduce.tasks` in the job configuration object

or

`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job#setNumReduceTasks(int reducerCount);` method can be used.

Comment: Thank you so much Madhu.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html) documentation,

**Reducer** reduces a set of intermediate values which share a key to a smaller set of values.

**Reducer** has 3 primary phases:

**Shuffle**

Reducer is input the grouped output of a Mapper. In the phase the framework, for each Reducer, fetches the relevant partition of the output of all the Mappers, via HTTP.

**Sort**

The framework groups Reducer inputs by keys (since different Mappers may have output the same key) in this stage.

**Reduce**

In this phase the `reduce(Object, Iterator, OutputCollector, Reporter)` method is called for each  pair in the grouped inputs.

The output of the **Reduce task** is typically written to the FileSystem via `OutputCollector.collect(Object, Object)`.

Note that apart from Reducer, **Combiner** also invoke **reduce** function since it is implementing **Reducer** interface.

***`Reducer`*** is a class, which contain `reduce` function as below

```
    protected void reduce(KEYIN key, Iterable<VALUEIN> values, Context context
                        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

***`Reduce task`*** is program running on a node, which is executing ***`reduce`*** function of `Reducer` class.

Comment: Thank you so much Ravindra. Appreciate your detailed explanation.